# How do I remove duplicates from this?

Tags: python

I am writing values like these to a file:

```
(u'fresh', 4.3557350075853982)  
(u'fresh', 6.6629604801359461)
(u'focus', 6.4398169288217364)


p= zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)        #('object' , score)
with codecs.open("scores.txt","a") as t:
        for x in p:
            if not x:
                print>>t, x
```

What I am trying to do is remove duplicates from being written to the file. So I am trying to check if x already exists, not to write it again. How can I do so given that it is a zipped component.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
"""(u'fresh', 4.3557350075853982)  
(u'fresh', 6.6629604801359461)
(u'focus', 6.4398169288217364)"""


p= zip(vectorizer.get_feature_names(), idf)        #('object' , score)
outputted = set()
with codecs.open("scores.txt","a") as t:
        for x in p:
            if x[0] in outputted: continue
            print>>t, x
            outputted.add(x[0])
```

This is assuming you want to remove duplicates for just the 'object' -- if you consider duplicates as the (object, score) pair being exactly the same, replace `x[0]` from the answer with `x`

Essentially what this is doing is, it is keeping track of object/scores you have already outputted, and doesn't re-output object/scores that have been outputted for an object previously.

Comment: Hi, I tried both approaches, it still doesn't seem to remove duplicate 'fresh'